# Elixir multiplicação em uma Map não funciona. Por quê?

Tags: programação-funcional, map, elixir

Sou novo em Elixir e não estou entendendo o retorno da função.

```
list = %{"100" => 1, "50" => 2, "20" => 4, "10" => 8, "5" => 16, "1" => 32}

for {key, value} <- list, do: String.to_integer(key) * value
```

Ou

```
Enum.map(list, fn({key, value}) -> String.to_integer(key) * value end)
```

Retorna

```
' PdPPd'
```

Mas quando converto para String

```
for {key, value} <- list, do: "#{String.to_integer(key) * value}"
```

Retorna

```
["32", "80", "100", "80", "80", "100"]
```

Comment: Você quer manter a ordem ou quer algo funcional? O resultado saiu conforme esperado, já que a ordem não é mandatória de seguimento nessa construção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambos os códigos funcionam adequadamente, como pode ser visto [aqui](https://ideone.com/8QkWxJ). O problema que você está enfrentando ocorre na hora de exibir os resultados.

Quando você utilza o `IO.inspect` em uma coleção de inteiros, Elixir tenta converter esses valores em *strings*. Como os valores do seu exemplo são pontos de código válidos na tabela ascii, eles acabam sendo convertidos nos caracteres correspondentes (32: espaço; 80: P, 100: d; etc).

Para evitar que isso ocorra, você pode adicionar a opção `char_lists: :as_lists`. Exemplo:

```
IO.inspect Enum.map(list, fn{key, value} -> String.to_integer(key) * value end) , char_lists: :as_lists
```

Comment: Valeu!! Obrigado pela sugestão realmente não sabia.